# iOS - UITextView multiline being disable after changing text

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

I'm currently building a tableview and feeding information into the cell. In one of my prototype cell there was a `UITextView`. It looks ok if I build the project and display on simulator. However, if I change the text of `UITextView` programatically. The `UITextView` will disable multiline which only display one line string on centre and '...' at the end of the string.

here is my code in method `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];    
UITextView* label = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:0];
NSString* des = @"a long long long long string";
[label setText:des];
return cell;
```

[image]

What's wrong to my code.

Thanks!

xcode 6.4

Comment: you can try it with set the tag for textview in cell with nonzero value... because this is possible that other label having tag 0. Set textview tag to nonzero in tableview cell.

Comment: with much thanks!!! it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try it with set the tag for textview in cell with nonzero value... because this is possible that other label having tag 0. Set textview tag to nonzero in tableview cell.

by default the controls tag is 0. so we have to set tag more than 0 if we want to use the control using tag.